# jQuery .prepend() using class from another element if it starts with specific word

Tags: jquery, class, prepend

I want to prepend using another existing elements class in the elements that will be prepended. For the sake of avoiding confusion lets say that i only know that the parent elements class has word "box" in the beginning and lets say rest of the class is randomly generated.

Therefore i obviously cant write for example:

```
.prepend('<div class="box-something_more"></div>');
```

Because for all i know, the parent elements class might be "box-nothing" or "box-something-else" or millions of other things.

html structure:

```
<div class="box-something"> <!-- source of the box- class -->
    <div class="box-something_more"></div> <!-- prepended element -->
    <div class="box-something_evenmore"></div> <!-- prepended element -->

</div>

<div class="box-two"> <!-- source of the box- class -->
    <div class="box-two_more"></div> <!-- prepended element -->
    <div class="box-two_evenmore"></div> <!-- prepended element -->

</div>
```

So what needs to happen is that the elements that will be prepended get the beginning of their class from the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/tDUpD/2/

**Edit:** this seems to do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/tDUpD/3/

Comment: [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), or [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)?

Comment: @DavidThomas prepend() im not sure if that matters in this case.. the thing i want to achieve would still remain the same.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple elements that start with `class` of 'box'? You want to create multiple `div` elements?

Comment: @DavidThomas i want to use that full class name in the prepended div.

Comment: So there'll only ever be *one* `div` with a class beginning with `box`? Even *after* you've added further `div`s?

Comment: @DavidThomas Not exactly.. but for the sake of this.. lets say there is only one class that starts with "box-"

Comment: @muistooshort It's really hard to be precise when i dont know what im talking about. Though now i have better picture what i want myself..  so, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you had in mind? If not, please try to state your question more clearly:

**EXAMPLE:**

*HTML*

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="doo"></div>
```

*JS*

```
var childClasses = ["bar", "baz"];

$('.foo, .doo').each(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    $.each(childClasses, function(i, childClass) {
        $self.append($('<div/>', {
            'class': $self.attr('class') + "_" + childClass
        }));
    });
});
```

*= RESULTING HTML*

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="foo_bar"></div>
  <div class="foo_baz"></div>
</div>
<div class="doo">
  <div class="doo_bar"></div>
  <div class="doo_baz"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @polarblau As stated, lets say i have _no_ control over the parent classes so i cant just write ** $('.foo, .doo').each(function() ** cause for all i know it could be "foo-something" and "doo-something-else" in which case these would not point anywhere. So, it should be more like ** $('[class^="box-"]').each(function() ** and of course prepend instead of append. This is what i wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/tDUpD/3/ though i dont understand why i cant make it in this manner: http://jsfiddle.net/tDUpD/2/

Comment: You can use what ever selector you need. This is just an example on how to build the nested elements and assign classes based on the parent's class. `$('div').each(…)` would work as well in my example — but that's really not the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @polarblau though its a bit odd to ask me to be clearer when your answer isn't really that accurate. Thanks none the less. ( cant really mark your answer as the solution as it really isn't one straight up )

Comment: i mean when you obviously got the part about prepend and [class^="box-"] ( or should've ) Otherwise.. giving unclear answers to unclear questions isn't that strange at all :)

Comment: For someone who doesn't know exactly what he's talking about (as you had stated in your comments), you sure are a bit picky what comes to the accuracy of the answer. Given your pretty blurry question — I don't believe your testy comment is really appropriate in this context. In any case, your edit indicates that my answer has at least "inspired" you and that's good enough for me. Moving on…

Comment: @polarblau Those things you failed to include in your example were about the only things i was very clear about. I might be somewhat picky about it.. it is great solution i just cant really mark it as the answer to my question as it isn't that entirely.

Comment: well.. as i didnt directly _ask_ anything in my edited "Question" im gonna give you some slack and mark this as the solution with some of my own edits. :)